# jquery tinysort

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, sorting

i want to sort a UL with tinysort.
which looks like this:

```
<ul id="menu" class="menu">  
<li> 
<a href="#"  class="resizable" style="height:14px;">Test1</a>  
</li> 
<li> 
<a href="#"  class="resizable" style="height:15px;">Test2</a>     
</li> 
<li> 
<a href="#"  class="resizable" style="height:10px;">Test3</a>     
</li>  
</ul>
```

i tried to sort by:

```
onclick="$('ul.menu&gt;li').tsort('a',{attr:'style',order:'desc'});"
```

but its creating some false results.
im using jqueryUIs resizeable to change the height of the elements and want to sort them 
by height after resizing.

can i access the style.height attribute somehow?
maybe another sorting plugin or a sort script will do that better?

**a solution would be a special attribute called heightvalue in  which is set to the 
height of the element. but how can i change the jqueryUI resizable that it would add me a 
value to that attribute?**

Comment: Does this mean your problem is solved? If so, instead of editing the question, please post as an answer and accept.

Comment: yea, i just had to wait 6 hours to do that and i still have to wait 3 :-)

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution.
i added the attribute "heightvalue" to each element
which im setting after resizing.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $( ".resizable" ).resizable({
            maxHeight: 100,
            minHeight: 14,
            stop: function(evn, ui) {
            $(this).attr("heightvalue", $(this).css('height'));
            alert( $(this).css('height') );
            }
        });


    });
    </script>
```

now, sorting works...